# How to search records with priority in magento

Tags: php, magento

We have four cities records with people's address...

For example four cities such as Delhi, Mumbai, Chennai, and Banglore

If peoples came from delhi means have to fetch records from Delhi listings address and then Mumbai, Chennai, Banglore

The first priority should be 1)Delhi 2)mumbai 3)chennai 4)banglore and so on

How to fetch records from datbase with their city wise

```
public function getSearchResults($params)
{
    $city = @$params['city'];
    $category_id = isset($params['category']) ? $params['category'] : "";
    $searchResultsCollection = Mage::getModel("listings/listings")->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*');
    $searchResultsCollection->addFieldToFilter("status", 1);

    try {
        if ($city != '') {
            $searchResultsCollection->addFieldToFilter("city", array('like' => $city));
        }

        if ($category_id != '') {
            $searchResultsCollection->addFieldToFilter('cat_ids', array(array('finset' => array($category_id))));
        }
        if ($limit != 'all') {
            $searchResultsCollection->getSelect()->limit($limit, $startFrom);
        }
        $searchResultsCollection->getSelect()->order("verification DESC");
        $searchResultsCollection->load();
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
    return $searchResultsCollection;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your problem with this coding? where you are stuck with? also you should mention fields of listing model

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a FIELD expression to your order method call;

```
->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(city, 'Delhi','Mumbai','Chennai','Bangalore')"))
```